# Como acessar o /localhost/?

Tags: apache, permissões

Instalei o Apache2 com o Mysql e o Phpadmin em um notebook com Ubuntu 15.10.

Fiz isto usando um usuário com perfil de administrador.

Agora, estou querendo acessar o /localhost/ com outro usuário mas não estou conseguindo, com a seguinte resposta:

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access / on this server. Apache/2.4.12
>   (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Como faço para acessar os arquivos no /localhost/ por todos os usuários no computador local?

Comment: Onde está localizada a pasta www(ou htdocs)?

Comment: Está em /var/www

Comment: Porque não altera para /home/seuuser/www? Assim não terá problemas com permissões de pasta do sistema.

Comment: Desculpe, Diego, mas no Apache2, de que modo configuro essa alteração?  Lembrando que o Apache2 foi instalado no usuário administrador. Agora quero acessa-lo por usuário sem o mesmo perfil.

Comment: Está utilizando algum virtual host ou está apenas com a configuração padrão de instação?

Comment: Apenas a instalação padrão, então editei o DocumentRoot mas não funcionou.

Comment: Qual a permissão da pasta /var/www, aparece algo no arquivo /var/log/apache2/error_log ? Já pensou em ativar o módulo "mod_userdir"? Ele permite que você sirva páginas http direto do seu diretório de usuário (aqui, no opensuse, os arquivos ficam em ~/public_html) acessando como http://localhost/~[USERNAME].

Comment: Poste o conteúdo do `virtualhost`. Os códigos no `httpd.conf`. Algo assim `<virtualhost> bla bla bla </virtualhost>`